# After button click I want to display the table and open new window

Tags: php, jquery

Only after first execution table is displayed and also outs_print.php file is displayed in new tab when again executed outward_print.php file is displayed in same tab.

I want table(outs_print.php file) to be displayed in new tab after button is clicked.

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
  <form name="out_print" action="out_print.php" method="post">
  <table class="table_1">
  <tr><td><label>Date Range From</label></td>
  <td><input type="date" name="from" /></td>

  <td><label>To</label></td>
  <td><input type="date" name="to"/></td></tr>

  <tr><td><label>Name</label></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td></tr></table>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" onclick="myFunction();"  class="button3"/>
  <script>
  function myFunction()
  {
    document.out_print.action = "outs_print.php";
    document.out_print.submit();                
  }
  </script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

outs_print.php

```
<?php

    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    $db = mysql_select_db("prs", $connection);
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){    
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $from = $_POST['from'];
    $to = $_POST['to'];
    if($name !=''||$from !=''||$to !='')
    {
?>

<html>
<body>
    <table border="1" bordercolor="#d6d6d6" class="tabl">
    <thead bgcolor="#FAFAFA">
    <tr>
    <th>No</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    </tr>  
    </thead>

    <tbody>

    <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM out WHERE (date between '$from' and '$to') AND (name = '$name')";
        $records=mysql_query($sql);
        while($out=mysql_fetch_assoc($records))
        {
             echo "<tr>";
             echo "<td>".$out['no']."</td>";
             echo "<td>".$out['date']."</td>";
             echo "<td>".$out['name']."</td>";
             echo "<td>".$out['price']."</td>";
             echo "</tr>";
        }
    ?>

          <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Okay");
            var win = window.open("out_print.php", "out_print.php");
            win.focus();
          </script>

    <?php
       }
    }
    ?>

    </tbody>
    </table> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers here are on the right track, but `target="_blank"` will create a new tab/window with each form submission.

If you want a new tab/window to be launched on the first submission of the form, and any subsequent submissions of the form to return their result in the tab/window which was created on the first submission, giving the target a name will do that.

```
<form name="out_print" method="post" action="out_print.php" target="out_print_response">
....
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp

Answer (score 1):

Just add target="_blank" to the form element :)

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp

Comment: Except `target="_blank"` will launch a new tab/window for every submission.

Comment: Ok then you can remove it after sumit width removeAttribute(target)

Comment: But doing so would then mean that the first submission would open in a new tab/window, and then subsequent submissions would open in the tab/window where the form was submitted. This is not the behaviour the OP was wanting. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

add `target="_blank"` like this:

```
<form name="out_print" action="out_print.php" method="post" target="_blank">
```

target attribute in form specifies where to display the response that is received after submitting the form. `target="_blank"` display the response in `new tab`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Except `target="_blank"` will launch a new tab/window for every submission.